# Android InApp Purchase issue (-1002: Bad Response received)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have an app with IAP implemented and it works fine for most of the time. However, some installations are reporting a -1002 error code from IABHelper (which is not documented anywhere). Here's what the logs tell me (this happens right after the user returns from Google Play):

```
2013-05-03 11:40:03,781 774539 [main] ERROR: In-app billing error: Null data in IAB activity result.

2013-05-03 11:40:03,786 774544 [main] DEBUG: Purchase finished: IabResult: Null data in IAB result (response: -1002:Bad response received), purchase: null

2013-05-03 11:40:03,803 774561 [main] ERROR: Error purchasing: IabResult: Null data in IAB result (response: -1002:Bad response received)
```

Why error `-1002` occurs?

Is is a problem with Google play or my client implementation?

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Got the same problem, did you found a solution?

Comment: I have this problem too, any answer?

Comment: I have the same problem. Test purchases work just fine, but all real ones fail with the same error (-1002).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
Issue was that i restricted permission of Google Play Market to run in background.
That's why Play Market not launched and my application got bad response.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when the in-app billing was in a fragment, I solved it solved by moving it to an activity.